# jQuery ajax - same origin policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, same-origin-policy

This website (http://www.thekatespanos.com/scrabble-score-calculator/) has a button where a user can validate the word they have typed in against some online dictionaries.   I understand how the code works in terms of the jQuery code, but I don't fully get **how** it does what it does as it pulls in data from other webpages..

Here is an example:-

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/' + word,
        type: 'GET',
        error: function() {
            $('#validationDC').html('<span class="invalid">error loading from</span> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/' + word + '">Dictionary.com</a>.');   
        },
        success: function(res) { 
            var definition = $(res.responseText).find('.results_content').html();
            if (definition) {
                $('#validationDC').html('<span class="word valid">' + word + '</span> is a valid word according to <a target="_blank" href="http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/' + word + '">Dictionary.com</a>.');
                //$('#definitionDC').html(definition);
            }
            else {
                $('#validationDC').html('<span class="word invalid">' + word + '</span> is not a valid word according to <a target="_blank" href="http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/' + word + '">Dictionary.com</a>.');
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.loading').remove();
        }
    });
```

This code sends a jQuery ajax request to dictionary.reference.com to validate the word entered on the application and parses the returned data to identify whether or not the word is valid.

How is this possible, given the same origin policy?  Can somebody explain as I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Possibly, but there's a lot going on there.  I would appreciate a reason as to why this code in particular works - I'm fairly new to Javascript so anything more specific would be really helpful..

Comment: They run it through a proxy that brings back JSONP.

Comment: How did you find this?  Where in the code would I find evidence that this is the case?  Apologies for noob questions, but I'm still learning.

Comment: I hit view source, then Ctrl+F, then `<script` then hit next until I found a likely looking file name.

Comment: OK..I understand how to find and read the code (that's how I came up with the question in the first place)..  What I don't get it how this works.  If the code does run through a proxy to return JSONP, where in the code do I find this?

Comment: I've also looked and cannot find the code mentioned by Quentin. It does appear that jQuery is referenced at least 3x, though...

Comment: I think it's the 'jquery.xdomainajax.js' file that does the trick - but i've not gone past there to see *how* it does it, sorry... :)